# Como diminuir a sensibilidade do scroll do touchpad no VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Eu literalmente já vasculhei e não encontrei nenhuma opção no **VScode** que resolvesse esse problema no *scroll* do *touchpad*, pois quando você está editando o código e quer ir para uma determinada seção e se for deslizado para ambas as direções cima, direita, baixo e esquerda é muito rápido a sensibilidade do *scroll*.

**Sensibilidade do Touchpad**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Sensibilidade do Mouse**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas configurações do computador tem como diminuir, mas vai efetar em geral ao usar o *touchpad* em outros programas no **VScode** não tem nenhuma opção para diminuir a sensibilidade e deixar semelhante ao do mouse?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37727#issuecomment-655410154

Answer (score 4):

Bom não tenho certeza que vai dar certo pq não tenho o ambiente para testar precisamente. Mas aqui tem alguma configs que podem te ajudar

Primeiro na opção `Editor: Mouse Wheel Scroll Sensitivity` coloque um valor menor que `1`, tipo `0.2` ou `0.1`. Esse evento deve reduzir a sensibilidade do `Touch` tb.

```
"editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 0.2
```

Depois, desmarque a opção `Editor: Scroll Beyond Last Line`, dessa forma o `scroll` sempre vai parar na última linha de código e não lá no final da página como mostra na sua imagem.

```
"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false
```

E por último, ative o `Smooth`, "Editor: Smooth Scrolling, isso pode ajuda a atenuar ainda mais a velocidade do `scroll`, ou pelo menos dar um tipo de delay que vai te ajudar a ver o código passando com mais "calma" na tela.

```
"editor.smoothScrolling": true
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: funcionou aqui amigo, diminuiu um pouco a velocidade do scroll do touchpad, mas mesmo assim continua um pouco rápido as opções também afetam o mouse deixando a sensibilidade do mesmo lenta quando mexe nas opções.

Comment: @felipecardozo acho que vc não consegue configurar individualmente velocidade do mouse e do touch, é uma config só para os dois... Na  config do seu Sistema Operacional talvez tenha mais opções...

Answer (score 0):

Aqui resolveu seguinda a dica do @hugocsl, mas settando o `"Editor: Mouse Wheel Scroll Sensitivity"` pra um valor decimal bem baixo, e.g. `0,0045`.
Nessa, o scroll do mouse praticamente não funciona mais, e uma meia-solução(que funciona) pra isso é settar o `"Editor: Fast Scroll Sensitivity"` para `1000`, dessa forma ao segurar <kbd>ALT</kbd> é possível usar o scroll do mouse normalmente.

Nota: O efeito desse fix aparentemente na lista de arquivos parece ser parcial.